# Converting a Matrix Class into IplImage*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I do have a class of Matrix and I access to it with two loops and have stored in it all the values I wanted to have in it.

```
Matrix MatriceJ(width, height);
for (int i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<height;j++)
    {
        MatriceJ.at(i,j)=....
    }
}
```

But now, I would like to store the MatriceJ in an IplImage* for that I can multiply its different elements, one by one, with the other IplImages.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: I dont understand why you have written  `Matrix MatriceJ`. Should it not be `Mat MatriceJ` ?

Comment: But I have created a class called Matrix to manipulate it easily and store in it values.

Comment: This question is not answerable as long as you don't state what `Matrix` exactly is.

Comment: @ZeusM I doubt that you have created a class better than opencv's `Mat`. Please use the same class. Dont reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. I assume the data to be unsigned char and one channel, please adjust accordingly.

```
// Create the image
int depth = IPL_DEPTH_8U; // please adjust
int channels = 1;         // please adjust
IplImage* img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height), depth, channels);

// Now assume there is a matrix MatriceJ
// Copy the data to our newly created IplImage*
for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    uchar* ptr = (uchar*)(img->imageData + i*img->widthStep);
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        ptr[j] = MatriceJ(i,j);
    }
}
```